# Magento2 importer importing only 400 rows everytime

Tags: magento2, import, admin-panel, importexport, development

I need to import 19000 price list in Magento system. My client break it into bunch of 5000 each.

While importing we noticed a weird behaviour that everytime when importing every batch only 400 products price get updated, after that it stuck in an endless loop only loader "Please Wait" comes.

No error is been displayed and the status is in-progress.

Every time it get stuck after 400 SKUs.

I checked in network and receiving a 502 badgateway. Any Suggestions ???

Any idea or suggestions why ??

Thanks

Comment: then the best way to do it with the helps of standalone script just write a script and by using foreach loop you can achieve this

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179455/magento-2-update-prices-with-csv

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the solution.

On checking the network tab the Ajax was returning 502 error.

**Solution of 502** -
We were having two instance separate for frontend and backend. We recently changes the admin identifier in **app/etc/env.php** but not changed that on server side so all requests from new admin identifier were going to frontend instance.

Also we had Cloudfare CDN that times out after 1.5 minutes of time, till then only 400 records used to update.

So pointing the new identifier to backend instance and bypass the cloudfare for a while fixed the issue.